# Bloquear ordenação alfabética no DatagridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, classificação

Meu DataGridView recebe dados de produtos de um banco de dados. São eles: descrição, preço unitário e quantidade. Programaticamente acrescentei uma coluna subtotal e adicionei o cálculo de preço unitário * quantidade. À medida que adiciono itens no datagrid, uma função faz este cálculo e adiciona o valor na linha correta. O problema acontece quando adiciono itens cujos nomes iniciam-se pela mesma letra; O Datagrid agrupa estes produtos e bagunça a ordem dos subtotais.

Meu código:

```
        foreach (int i in numerolinha) //adiciona valores no subtotal do datagrid
        {
            dgvpProd.Rows[i].Cells["Subtotal"].Value = qtxpreco[i];
        }

        foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dgvpProd.Columns)//Bloqueia as colunas do Datagrid
        {
            column.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
        }
```

O segundo foreach foi uma tentativa de solução bloqueando a ordenação de colunas pelo usuário, mas não resolve o problema da ordem alfabética. Alguma ajuda?

[image: valores desordenados]
Atualização: Descobri que a ordenação não é alfabética, mas sim pela ordem em que os itens foram cadastrados no BD. Itens que possuem id's menores são inseridos no topo do DatagridView e vice-versa. Ainda sem solução.

Comment: Como esta a estrutura da `query` que popula o `datagridview`?

Comment: Qual é o campo que é o critério de ordenação?

Comment: Não entendi muito bem a questão da estrutura mas se for a sequência em que os dados são salvos, seria essa: id, descrição, preço unitário, total e subtotal; sendo que id fica oculto e subtotal é uma coluna adicional que não está no BD. Na segunda questão: o critério desejado é a ordem de inserção, mas parece que está ordenando por itens de mesmo nome.

Comment: Dener, sua pergunta me deu uma pista: acho que está sendo ordenado por ID já que este campo está oculto. Vou tentar criar uma restrição para nao permitir 2 produtos com mesmo ID, até porque é ilógico dois itens iguais já que eu posso atribuir quantidade.

Comment: Vc esta populando o datagridview por uma query? Se for mostre-me como esta sua query, e mostre a rotina que popula o datagridview todo, com os campos: `descricao`, `preco unitario`, `quantidade`, `subtotal`.

Comment: Você pode ter dois itens iguais, porem eles podem se diferenciar em algum aspecto, mais não sei se é requisito do seu sistema.

Comment: itemTableAdapter.Insert(id_orcam, id_produto, quantidade, preco_item);
itemTableAdapter.Fill(vorc2DataSet.Item);
dgvpProd.DataSource = produtoTableAdapter.GetDataByIDOrc(id_orcam); //Este é um resumo da rotina

Comment: Este último trecho atualiza o Datagrid com a seguinte query: SELECT MAX(id) AS Expr1 FROM Orcamento que já está armazenada no datasource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estudando a linguagem SQL, descobri que posso criar uma coluna "temporária" ou "virtual" e ainda mostrar os valores já calculados sem precisar fazer isso pelo DataGridView. Simplesmente criei uma query que fez todo o trabalho para que eu não precisasse me preocupar com erros de cálculos nos casos de reordenação das colunas. Segue a query:

```
SELECT Produto.nome AS Produto, Item.quantidade AS Quantidade,
Item.preco_item AS Preço, 
Item.quantidade * Item.preco_item AS Subtotal
FROM ((Item INNER JOIN
         Orcamento ON Item.id_orcam = Orcamento.id) INNER JOIN
         Produto ON Item.id_produto = Produto.id)
WHERE (Orcamento.id = ?)
```

A parte mais importante foi a 3ª linha desta query que criou a coluna "Subtotal" já calculada como eu precisava.
Espero que seja útil para outras pessoas.